# Bitcoin-core download more then blockchain size

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have installed bitcoin-core on my digitalocean droplet and configured with the following bitcoin.conf :

```
datadir=/mnt/volume_name/Bitcoin
dbcache=1000
txindex=1
server=1
rpcuser=rpcuser
rpcpassword=rpcpassword
rpcport=8332
```

Then I start daemon, it begin to synchronize. Volume size is 500Gb, I thought it will be enought space for bitcoin blockchain, wich for now is around 414 Gb. But, after a few days I realized that the volume is full!

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
--- // ---
/dev/sda        496G  471G  4.0K 100% /mnt/volume_name
--- // ---
```

At the moment it stoped working and obvious it cant start again. Why it continue to fill all space on the disk? I know it has to be some misconfiguration, but I don't understand what exectly is wrong.

Comment: I think blockchain is currently around 441G, not 414G...

Comment: Use the du command to explore disk usage of your system.

Comment: If you don't plan to use the transaction index, you can just purge it out in order to free some space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction index, that you enabled, is sized at multiple GB (>10). Disable it, and then it's much more likely that it'll fit.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: @alex8327492 After you disable it, you can find and remove the transaction index files, that won't damage the rest of the datadir